Why won't this program display correctly?
I have this HTML page which is meant to display a to-do list and allow users to add tasks to it
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>To-Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="/todolist.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
        
        <ul class="todo-list">
            <!-- List items will go here -->
        </ul>
        
        <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="Add a new item">
        <button type="button" id="add-todo">Add To Do</button>
    </body>
</html>

and this script which should use the button from the HTML page to create an array of to-dos and display them on the webpage
// get list from local storage
const todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo-list')) || []

// create consts
const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const input = document.getElementById('new-todo')
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-todo')

// create/add list items
const renderTodos = () => {
    // clear li's before we recreate them
    todoList.innerHTML = ''
    // loop through list of items and create li elements
    todos.forEach(todo => {
        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.textContent = todo.text
        li.className = 'todo'
        todoList.append(li)
    })
}

// button event listener
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (input.value) {
        todos.push({ text: input.value, completed: false });
        localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(todos));
        input.value = '';
        renderTodos();
    }
});
renderTodos()

Goal is for the user to type and submit a todo, and it will show up on the webpage. The page will display all the HTML elements, but the javascript doesn't add elements. Or at least the javascript doesn't display the elements that were put in local storage.
Seems like this code should work, I must be missing something.

Have you seen the console log for errors and warnings in your browser dev tools?

check your debugger,--> todoList is null

That html does not have an item with id="todo-list" (there is one with that class, but not id).  Therefore document.getElementById('todo-list') returns null.  I don't understand how you expected this to work.

You used document.getElementById('todo-list') but have added <ul class="todo-list"> as a class.
The selector for ul is .todo-list when you use class. To have getElementById work on this, you have to put this in id.
Fixed ->
    <ul id="todo-list">
        <!-- List items will go here -->
    </ul>
    
    <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="Add a new item">
    <button type="button" id="add-todo">Add To Do</button>

